# jQuery table disappears on the first click and appears after the next one

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, onclick, onload

I have simple table made in jQuery:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Al-Ar</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Ar-D</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">E-Ha</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-4">Ha-J</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-5">K-Mo</a></li>
  </ul>
  <table class="tablica">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="tr1">
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tr">
        <td>
          <div id="tabs-1">
            <table class="pol">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td class="td10" colspan="4">Al..Ar</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="td1"><a href="1.html">1</a></td>
                  <td class="td2">1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="td1"><a href="2.html">2</a></td>
                  <td class="td2">2</td>
                </tr>
                ...
                <tr>
                  <td class="td1"><a href="205.html">205</a></td>
                  <td class="td2">205</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tr1">
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

(On the start page only the first page of the table is displayed)

Plus script:

```
<script>
$('#tabs a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var url = "./tabsContent1.php";
  var urlId = $(this).attr("href");
  // ajax load from href
  $(".tabs-content").load(url + " " + urlId);
});
</script>
```

Where tabsContent1.php contains the rest of the table.
Unfortunately, the above code causes that when any element of the table is clicked, it disappears! Only the table of contents bar is visible. After clicking on any page, everything returns to normal. So this problem only appears on the first click.
An additional problem is the fact that the pages from the table (these are interactive links) appear full-screen despite the script on the main page:

```
<script>
    <!--
    onload=function(){
      for(i=0;d=document.getElementsByTagName('a')[i++];){
       if (d.href.match(/.*hotel\d+\.html/)){
         d.onclick=function(){window.open(this.href,'a','width=740px, height=750px, resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, left=20px, top=20px');return false}
       }
      }
    }
    //-->
</script>
```

How to change it?

Comment: It hasn't been necessary to put scripts in HTML comments for many years.

Comment: Where is the `.tabs-content` element in your HTML?

Comment: You should only bind the click handler to the links in the table of contents, not all links in the table.

Comment: there shouldn't be a " " in your url

Comment: in your main function you need to preventDefault on all a tags that match

Comment: I don't know javascript at all, I got the code from a question in another forum. Unfortunately, `.tabs-content` is nowhere in html. Where would I add it?